# how to protect wordpress website

Tags: plugins, login, options

i completed my website but i want to protect my site using login option.when i enter my site its goes to login page if user logged in after home page will display.how can do that if there any plugin.....
But temporaly i put below code in front-page.php.  login option will display overlay of my front page. but its not a correct way.
if logged in 
.logged-in .login_page{display:none;}

if i logout
 #loggedout .login_page{display:block;} in below code 
 
" title="Logout">Logout

```
 <div class="login_page">
  <div class="loginInfo">
    <?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>
    <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
      <div class="userIndex">
        <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="20" />
      </div>
      <div class="pwdIndex">
        <input class='pwd' type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" />
      </div>
      <div class="submitIndex">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" />
      </div>      
      <p style="display:none">
        <label for="rememberme">
          <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" />
          Remember me</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
      </p>
    </form>
    <a style="display:none" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a style="display:none" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" id="logoutin">logout</a><br />
  <?php }?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the header.php of your theme you can add the following code @ the beginning of the php code

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  header( 'Location: /' );
} else {
  header( 'Location: /wp-login.php' );
}
```

If the user is not logged it will be redirected to the login form else it will be redirected to the /home page or tha page u want.